# best practice for multi robot simulation

Tags: multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Could anybody let me know what is the best practice for multi-robot simulation in ROS ?
I want to simulate both an aerial vehicle and a ground vehicle in gazebo, and control them for the missions such as path-following and tracking objects.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30471/best-practice-for-multi-robot-simulation/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-26**:
To get meaningful answers, you need to say a lot more about what you are trying to accomplish.

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-03-26**:
I edited the previous one about what to do for multi-robot simulation.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-26**:
Incase you had not seen, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UmtylLDErQ shows multi robot simulation in stage (not in gazzebo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also be interested in the MORSE simulator:

http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/

I remember a video where Gilberto Echverria simulated an aerial vehicle following a ground vehicle or several robots following each other:

http://vimeo.com/9825826

http://vimeo.com/38334797

It´s release 0.5 at the moment but works with ROS...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0